# How to compare Character for empty space

Tags: ios, swift

I need to check if a Character is a space, how do you do that?

```
for (index, val) in (self.textField.text?.enumerated())! {
  if val == " " { // How?
    if index % 2 == 0 {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your solution works in swift 4. You might want to unwrap the optional (optional binding : if let, guard else)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NSCharacterSet to check for white space, including \n, \t, etc.

```
NSCharacterSet.whitespaces.contains(val.unicodeScalars.first!)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift, You can iterate directly over a String

```
   let phrase = "Hello, This is Test String."
        for chr in phrase {
            if chr == " " {
                print("White space")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the kind of *space* you're looking for. For "normal" spaces (0x20) your code should work. But it won't evaluate to `true` for "special" spaces.

Given the following string, which contains different kind of spaces,

```
let myString = "This\u{0020}text contains normal spaces\u{00a0}and\u{00a0}non-breaking\u{00a0}ones"
```

comparing to `" "` will result in finding 4 occurrences

```
let result1 = myString.enumerated().filter { $0.element == " " }

print(result1)
/* 
   [(offset: 4, element: " "), 
    (offset: 9, element: " "), 
    (offset: 18, element: " "), 
    (offset: 25, element: " ")] 
*/
```

But you can also use the whitespace CharacterSet. **Be aware**: this will evaluate to true for other whitespace-types (like newlines, tabs) as well.

```
let result2 = myString.unicodeScalars.enumerated().filter { 
                  CharacterSet.whitespaces.contains($0.element) 
              }

print(result2)
/*
    [(offset: 4, element: " "), 
     (offset: 9, element: " "), 
     (offset: 18, element: " "), 
     (offset: 25, element: " "), 
     (offset: 32, element: "\u{00A0}"), 
     (offset: 36, element: "\u{00A0}"), 
     (offset: 49, element: "\u{00A0}")]
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

easiest way

```
var str : String = textField.stringValue
for i in 0...str.count-1{
    var spaceChr : Character = str.removeFirst() //init
    if spaceChr == " " { //doit}
}
```